# where to set GCC library dependencies in Netbeans?

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, netbeans-7

I just started using Netbeans 7.3.1, and I am experiencing some trouble compiling my project. In terminal, I successfully compiled with the following code:

```
gcc -Wall one.c two.c three.c four.c -o gateway -lpthread
```

When I compile in Netbeans, I get errors like 'undefined reference to 'pthread_create'. So I need to add the '**-lpthread**' option, but I can't figure out where..

Any help would be much appreciated!!

EDIT: found it: I posted the solution below!

Kind regards,

Joe

Comment: -lphread is linking of thread library. I never use Netbeans any way But there must be linker option for linking external dependent libraries. You have to learn your tool first( like How to Compile/linking static/Dynamic library to your Final Executable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it!

Adding library dependencies to GCC in Netbeans:

```
File->Project Properties->Build->Linker->Libraries->add Library/add standard Library.
```

For example for the -lpthread or -pthread option:

```
add standard Library --> Posix Threads
```